# Is this a good strategy to undo git stuff?

Tags: git, revert, git-reset, git-revert

Until now, if I ever commited and pushed something wrong to the master branch, my way of solving it was, assume the the git log looks like

```
commit bad_hash
commit another_bad_hash
commit yet_another_bad_hash
commit good_hash
```

The way I 'solved' the situation in the past was :

```
git reset --hard good_hash
git push -f origin master
```

And yes, that will work... but did not seem very elegant, since it effectively remove the commit history.

So after situation which destroyed my ego, I checked out better methods, and came out with the git revert one, essentially I use now

```
git revert bad_hash another_bad_hash yet_another_bad_hash
git push origin master
```

The git revert will create three commits (one per reverted hash), after that, a push is needed to update the remote.

Now, question is, is this strategy correct? to me looks much better than the reset --hard, since the history of the repo is not trunkated, and if eventually someone wants to check why there were problems, they can always do a

```
git diff bad_hash
```

Is this reasoning correct or am I still missing basic concepts.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This workflow explains everything you need to know.  It's a great resource IMHO.

Credits: [Justin Hileman](http://justinhileman.info/article/changing-history/)

[image: Git Mess Workflow]

Comment: Can you please provide the source of the image? (It's pretty nice, I am sure whoever did this workflow has more stuff)

Comment: Sadly I believe I got this link through the great wide world of twitter.   So I don't have a link to the original page (if there was one).

Comment: I've found the source, I believe – I've added it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes -- `git revert` is absolutely the appropriate approach in this situation, as it preserves the history of the bad commit having been made, then later removed.

Comment: You mean git revert, don't you?

Comment: I agree with `git revert` for fixing published commits, but want to note the potential 'gotcha' when reverting merges.  This detailed in this article: http://git-scm.com/2010/03/02/undoing-merges.html.  It's in the section `Reverting the Revert`.

Answer (score 1):

Normally for "work in progress", I will make a sequence of commits, then do a `git rebase -i base` to clean up my history - consider that the reader (possibly yourself) will find this easier to see later on in the future.

Once I then push it, I will consider that history immutable, and will then prefer the `git revert` approach.

Comment: What if we are in a scenario where dirty or untested code has been already pushed to the remote?

Comment: Every time you do a non-fast-forward push, ie, cause the remote to 'lose' a sha1, it becomes annoying for other users to reconcile their histories.  You will have to make that judgement call yourself.

Comment: That's exactly what I mean, in order to prevent losing commit hashes, it is better to use git revert instead of git reset and then force a push, right?

Comment: Correct, just ask yourself: "Is it worth tidying up, or is the communication cost too high if other people can see these changes already?"